# BigQuery - Datetime vs Timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I looked on the documentation for google big query data types, checking the differences between TimeStamp to Datetime data types.

As I understand the main difference is:

> Unlike Timestamps, a DATETIME object does not refer to an absolute instance in time. Instead, it is the civil time, or the time that a user would see on a watch or calendar.

So when should I use Timestamp/Datetime?

Thanks

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In most cases you will want to use the [timestamp data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type). It refers to an absolute point in time. BigQuery interprets any timezone information and represents the time internally as a [UTC timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Very rarely would you use a [datetime data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime-type), which is a date and a time but no time zone. The example I like to give is that you'd use a datetime to represent pi day, 2017, since it occurs at `2017-03-14 15:09:26.535898` in each time zone separately.